# How to use the configuration processor with records

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I am using spring-boot-configuration-processor to generate a spring-configuration-metadata.json file.

When I use a class for my configuration, the description is taken from the javadoc above the field like in this example using Lombok:

```
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties("my.second.properties")
public class MySecondProperties {

    /**
     * This is the description for stringProperty
     */
    private final String stringProperty;

    /**
     * This is the description for booleanProperty
     */
    private final boolean booleanProperty;

    public MySecondProperties(@DefaultValue("default value for stringProperty") String stringProperty,
                              boolean booleanProperty) {
        this.stringProperty = stringProperty;
        this.booleanProperty = booleanProperty;
    }
}
```

However, when using records I do not manage to get the description. I have created a record as in the example below, but the description remains empty in the generated json-file.

```
/**
 * @param stringProperty This is the description for stringProperty
 * @param booleanProperty This is the description for booleanProperty
 */
@ConfigurationProperties("my.fourth.properties")
public record MyFourthProperties (@DefaultValue("default value for stringProperty") String stringProperty,
                                  boolean booleanProperty) {
}
```

How can I ensure that the description is filled when using records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 3.2.0, this doesn't seem to be possible.  If you want `spring-boot-configuration-processor` to generate property-level documentation, you need to use a non-record Java class, possibly with Lombok annotations.

[spring-projects/spring-boot#29403](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/29403) more specifically notes:

> ... there is no way to automatically generate descriptions in configuration metadata if you use `@ConfigurationProperties` with record class.

That GitHub pull request attempts to add support, but as of this writing it is incomplete and not part of the Spring library stack.

Comment: thank for this answer, this basically answers my question and what I noticed